# Changing the color of an automatically generated navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, xcode

I have multiple tabs (more than 5) in the tab bar in my app, and when this happens, xcode automatically makes the last tab a "more" tab and puts the last tabs in it. The problem is, I have navigation bars in the other tabs that are a different color than any of the default colors, and the automatically generated "more" tab is the default blue color. I was wondering if there was any way to change this?
Thanks a lot
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

or

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

See this answer for customizing the navigation bar colour of the "edit" modal view controller: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301050/changing-the-navigationbar-color-on-the-edit-screen-of-the-more-section)

Comment: That works for the more tab, but there is also an "edit" option in the nav bar that comes up with a "configure" screen. how do i change the color of that one?

Comment: I tried asking this question on the original post but maybe you would know: Where do I put the "viewDidLoad" part. i cant put it in the app delegate, so where?

Answer (score 1):

This reads to me like you actually want to change the color of a selected tabbaritem. If so, then this post has myriad solutions: [Custom colors in UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)

Otherwise, if you mean what you write in the title, you can change the color of a navigation bar by changing the `tintColor` property.

Answer (score 0):

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

place this in the AppDelegate under - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions